# What is the Cartesian product of $A=\{(1,2),(3,3)\}$ and $B=\{(2,4),(8,6),(5,3)\}?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

I know that $A\times B=\{(a,b)|a\in A,b\in B\}$ and $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}.$
 For $$A=\{(1,2),(3,3)\}$$ and $$B=\{(2,4),(8,6),(5,3)\},$$ $$A\times B=\{((1,2),(2,4)),((1,2),(8,6)),((1,2),(5,3)),((3,3),(2,4)),((3,3),(8,6)),((3,3),(5,3))\},$$ but what then?

Answer (score 3):

No "then"; your Cartesian product is fine as you wrote it down.